# electron-packager not installing all modules from node_modules

Tags: electron, electron-packager

`electron-packager .` not installing all modules from `node_modules` on Darwin platform.

When trying to start such packaged app, following error occurs:

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Cannot find module 'sudo-prompt'
    at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename
```

Both `package.json` and `node_modules` are in current folder.

I’ve tried to remove `node_modules` completely and refresh them with `npm install -production` but it didn't help to package the app correctly.

> package.json

```
"main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chokidar": "^1.7.0",
    "electron": "^1.6.11",
    "filesize": "^3.5.6",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "keymaster": "^1.6.2",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "peity": "^3.2.1",
    "sudo-prompt": "^7.1.0",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "unzip-stream": "^0.1.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chart.js": "^2.6.0",
    "filesize": "^3.5.10",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "sudo-prompt": "^7.1.0"
  }
```

Packaged app with `electron-packager` has  only `chart.js`  All other dependencies are missing.

```
.app/Contents/Resources/app $ npm ls
└─┬ chart.js@2.6.0
  ├─┬ chartjs-color@2.1.0
  │ ├─┬ chartjs-color-string@0.4.0
  │ │ └── color-name@1.1.2
  │ └── color-convert@0.5.3
  └── moment@2.18.1
```

Answer (score 4):

Just in case someone faces similar problem:

Removing duplicated `dependencies` modules from `devDependencies` solved the issue.